# How to get 'asin' tag from listings using nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nokogiri

I am trying to get the ASIN number from amazon html page using nokogiri but I am having no luck using xpath. I have tried it with firepath and I am still getting nothing. Would it be better to just get the URL and then run a ruby REGEX to get the ASIN out? If so how would the regex look like?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/new-releases/books/3839/ref=zg_bsnr_nav"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts doc.xpath('//zg_list').each do | node|
  p node['asin']
end
```

This is what I have when it prints out the url.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/new-releases/books/3839/ref=zg_bsnr_nav"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

l = doc.css('div.zg_image a').map { |link| 
  link['href'] 
  }
puts l # => /Introducing-ZBrush-4-Eric-Keller/dp/0470527641/ref=zg_bsnr_3839_20/183-0702383-0095048
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the `css` method in Nokogiri is much easier to work with than XPath. Given the HTML at the URL you posted, the following should retrieve the “asin” property for each item:

```
doc.css("div.zg_item").map { |e| e["asin"] }
```

I think the correct XPath would be something like:

```
doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'zg_item') and @asin]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either CSS accessors or XPath:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/new-releases/books/3839/ref=zg_bsnr_nav"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

# CSS
# puts doc.search('div[class="zg_item zg_sparseListItem"]').each { |n| p n['asin'] }

# XPath
puts doc.search('//div[@class="zg_item zg_sparseListItem"]').each { |n| p n['asin'] }

# >> "1934356549"
# >> "0596802471"
# >> "B004M8T01Q"
# >> "0596809158"
# >> "0470943327"
# >> "B004MMEJ36"
# >> "1935182641"
# >> "B004RDOPJI"
# >> "1449390501"
# >> "1449389716"
# >> "B004IWRH4I"
# >> "0470527641"
# >> "0735650926"
# >> "1430231475"
# >> "0321751043"
# >> "B004NBZ65G"
# >> "B004TMNSJK"
# >> "0132091518"
# >> "144030842X"
# >> "1430234040"
# >> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the xpath version, I am still trying to get use to using xpath during searches.

Comment: XPath is powerful, but sometimes CSS accessors are the more direct path. The best thing is to see which is the path of least resistance for a particular search and go with it, because, in the long run as code moves to maintenance mode, being able to quickly grasp what node is being searched for becomes more important than which was the cooler/more macho thing to write in.

Comment: Note that you can make this simpler by using the XPath to select all the `asin` attribute values directly: `puts doc.xpath('//div[@asin]/@asin')`